# Editar um elemento dentro de um objeto, dentro de um array, com Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql, mongoose

To precisando de um help! Sou novo com Node.JS e resolvi "criar um sistema" para por em prática o que já sei e criar desafios para incentivar meu aprendizado!
Fiz um workshop iniciante (com o Jean Carlo Suissa) que me deu uma boa base, mas preciso de "algo mais"!

Já pesquisei bastante, mas ainda não consegui resolver o problema abaixo:

#### Schema

[Empresa](https://github.com/antonellisantos/api.SIGContabilESACOL/blob/master/modules/empresa/schema.js)

```
, ativa: {type: Boolean, default: true}
, prestacao_servico:
  [ { inicio: {type: Date, default: Date.now, trim: true}
  , fim: {type: Date, default: '', trim: true}
    }
  ]
```

Toda vez que for renovado um contrato *(ativar)* ou a empresa for cadastrada, será inserido um elemento no array **prestacao_servico**  determinando a data de **inicio** deste contrato,  com o campo **fim** tendo valor nulo e o booleano **ativa** será definido para *true*.
E quando a empresa for desativada *(desativar)* deverá ser buscando dentro do array **prestacao_servico** o item que tem o campo **fim** nulo *(só podendo haver um item deste timpo no array)* e trocar seu valor para a data de encerramento `Date.now()`, também deverá ser definido o valor de **ativa** para *false*.

#### Exemplo:

```
{
  "_id": "54eec2379881c0d032856dd5",
  "razao_social": "Empresa 1 EIRELI me",
  "__v": 3,
  "contato": {
    "telefone": "1212341234",
    "celular": "12123451234",
    "email": "empresa@empresa1.com.br"
  },
  "endereco": {
    "cep": "12345123",
    "logradouro": "Rua A",
    "bairro": "Bairro A",
    "cidade": "Cidade 1",
    "uf": "RJ",
    "pais": "Brasil",
    "complemento": "",
    "numero": "123"
  },
  "simples_nacional": {
    "codigo": "123412341234"
  },
  "documentos": {
    "cnpj": "12123123123412",
    "inscricao_estadual": "12345678"
  },
  "opcao": {
    "sociedade": 1,
    "enquadramento": 1,
    "tributacao": 2
  },
  "prestacao_servico": [
    {
      "_id": "54eec2379881c0d032856dd6",
      "fim": "2015-02-26T07:06:14.741Z",
      "inicio": "2015-01-08T21:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": "54eec305f32a497533dc8eb1",
      "fim": "2015-02-26T07:08:42.451Z",
      "inicio": "2015-02-26T06:53:57.543Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": "54eec7505b3f2dd13688589d",
      "fim": null,
      "inicio": "2015-02-26T07:12:16.775Z"
    }
  ],
  "ativa": true
}
```

A empresa acima esta *ativa* (`"ativa": true`) e teve seu contrato iniciado no momento **2015-02-26T07:12:16.775Z**.
Ao desativá-la, o campo **fim**, do objeto cujo **_id** é *54eec7505b3f2dd13688589d*, deverá receber o valor correspondente ao "momento da desativação".

#### Problema:

Como localizar a *empresa* (pelo **_id**), em seguida localizar o item (em **prestacao_servico**) que tem o valor de **fim** nulo e editá-lo inserindo o momento?
Já utilizei a query `{_id: req.params.id, prestacao_servico: {$elemMatch: {fim: null}}}` dentro do `find`, porém utilizar o `$elemMatch` não faz diferença pois não terá outra empresa com o mesmo ID, até porquê o campo `documentos.cnpj` é definido como único.
O aggregate não retornou resultado algum.

Consegui uma solução, mas me parece ser uma grande gambiarra:

```
_Model.findOne({_id: req.params.id, "prestacao_servico.fim": null}, function(err, data){
  if(err) {
    // ERRO
  }
  var count = 0
  , i
  ;
  data.prestacao_servico.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    if(element.fim === null) {
      count++;
      i = index;
    }
  });
  if(count > 1) {
    // ERRO
  }
  else {
    data.prestacao_servico[i].fim = Date.now();
    data
    .save(function(e, d) {
      if(err) {
        // ERRO
      }
      else {
        // DATA
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Alguma dica?

## SOLUÇÃO

Segui meu raciocínio, apliquei as melhorias citadas pelo Sergio e procurei melhorar alguns aspectos, também. Por fim, terminou assim:

```
  var dados = req.params
    , query = {_id: dados.id}
    ;
  var promise = _Model.findOne(query).exec();
  promise
    .then(function(e) {
      ps = e.prestacao_servico.filter(function(item) {
        return !item.fim;
      });
      if(ps.length !== 1) throw new _SigError();
      ps[0].fim = Date.now();
      e.save();
      return e;
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      cb(null, data, res);
    })
    .then(null, function(err) {
      cb(err, null, res);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Acho que tem mesmo de ser por esse caminho. Sugiro uma pequena alteração no código mas basicamente a tua ideia é certa:

```
_Model.findOne({_id: req.params.id, "prestacao_servico.fim": null}, function(err, data){
    if(err) {
        return 'Erro!'; // é importante dar return aqui para não continuar
    }
    var ativos = data.prestacao_servico.filter(function(ps){
        return !ps.fim; // assumindo que tem null e não "null" (string)
    });
    if (ativos.length > 1) return 'Erro! Há mais que um registo ativo!';
    if (!ativos) return 'Erro! Todos os registos estão fechados!';
    ativos[0].fim = Date.now();
    data.save(function(err, data) { // repara que aqui tinhas "(e, d)" mas em baixo usas "err" e não "e"
      if(err) { 
        // ERRO
      }
      else {
        // OK, dar confirmação ao usuário
      }
    });
});
```

Outra opção é usares `findOneAndUpdate([query], [doc], [options], [callback])`, mas o código dentro da *callback* é identico.